# Como determinar qual arquivo HTML deve ser exibido como entrada no Jersey?

Tags: java, xml, jersey

Eu estou tentando encontrar uma forma de prover uma página de entrada correta no Jersey.  Uma página de login quando não houver um usuário logado, caso contrário eu devo exibir uma outra página inicial que irá chamar serviços RESTful desenvolvidos com Jersey e que irão mudar a interface da página inicial quando houver usuário logado.

Abaixo a configuração do arquivo `web.xml`:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Qualquer solução é válida desde que utilize a configuração do `web.xml` para facilitar. Não acho conveniente ter de criar um serviço para retornar cada uma dessas páginas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é direcionar usuários não logados para uma determinada página, você pode criar um filtro ([*Filter*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)) para verificar se o status do usuário e, caso não esteja logado, redirecioná-lo para a URL correta.

Além disso, o mesmo filtro poderia verificar se a URL acessada é a raiz da aplicação para então redirecionar o usuário para a respectiva página inicial.

Ao desenvolver aplicações com Jersey, eu evito usar páginas estáticas e também o `<welcome-file-list>`, preferindo fazer o tratamento via código, já que os *paths* são também todos definidos via código também.

Comment: Não acaba sendo mais complicado ter que trabalhar com `Viewable` e criar uma classe para retornar conteúdo html?

Será que não existiria uma configuração para instanciar o arquivo `web.xml` e resquistar um `redirectTo()` para a primeira ou para a segunda página?

Comment: @LuizFilipe Eu geralmente não uso HTML puro e sim Jersey + Freemarker. De qualquer forma, usar um Filtro da API Servlet não exige trabalhar com Viewable.

Comment: isso mesmo sei que não impede, e pode ter certeza que o Filter será de grande ajuda, contudo minha pergunta se restringe em como redirecionar entre as páginas que ficam na configuração `<welcome-files-list>`

Comment: @LuizFilipe Hum... não sei se estou entendendo o que você quer. O `welcome-file-list` não é uma lista de páginas do site, mas uma lista de nomes de arquivo padrão quando o usuário acessa uma URL sem especificar a página. Usando o exemplo da pergunta, se o usuário digitar `/app/pasta` na URL, o servidor vai procurar por `index.html` no caminho `/app/pasta/index.html` (a partir da pasta do app). Se ele não encontrar esse arquivo, então o servidor vai procurar por `/app/pasta/login.html`.

Comment: @LuizFilipe **Se** eu estou entendendo corretamente, você deve especificar apenas `index.html` no web.xml e, em verificar no filtro se o usuário não está logado, redirecionando-o para `login.html`. Se o login for executado com sucesso, aí você redireciona o usuário para o `index.html` ou simplesmente para a pasta base da aplicação. Se o formulário de login for verificar com um submit para um servlet, apenas faça um redirect. Se o login for feito via Ajax, então você pode usar o `window.location.href` para redirecionar o usuário para a outra página.

Comment: Essa é uma boa solução!